# How to get layout coordinates?

Tags: android

I have two layouts inside one layout. I would like to get `GirdLayout` coordinates. I've tried `gridLayout.getTop()` etc. but all of them return 0, even though grid starts almost in center. How can I get `GridLayout` coordinaters?

XML:

```
 <LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout>...</LinearLayout>
    <GridLayout>…</GridLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

EDIT:

activity code:

```
public class LoginActivity extends Activity {

    GridLayout gridLayout;
    LinearLayout linearLayout, generalLayout;

    int lTop, lBottom, lRight, lLeft;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);

        gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
        linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
        generalLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.generalLayout);

        lTop = gridLayout.getTop();
        lBottom = gridLayout.getBottom();
        lRight = gridLayout.getRight();
        lLeft = gridLayout.getLeft();
    }
}
```

Comment: post more code (where are you calling getTop from)?

Comment: in `OnCreate`, just after `(GridLayout) gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout)`

Comment: no silly,  please edit your question and add that there.

Comment: Sorry, I hope now it's alright?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
Rect r = new Rect();
gridLayout.getWindowVisibleDisplayFrame(r);  
int x = r.centerX();
int y = r.centerY();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing your "top getting" after the activity has been started and is now visible to the user by moving this logic to the activity's onStart override like so,

EDIT:  also try using getX(), getY() instead.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login_layout);
    gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridLayout);
    linearLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.imageLayout);
    generalLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.generalLayout);
}

@Override
protected void onStart() {
    super.onStart();
    lTop = gridLayout.getY();
    lLeft = gridLayout.getX();
    lBottom = lTop + gridLayout.getHeight();
    lRight = lLeft + gridLayout.getWidth();

}
```

Comment: It still returns 0 for all values